# Wordpress plugin form submitting to database on every browser refresh

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin, backend is working as I need but I am facing issue in frontend, I have created a shortcode page from I am posting few values to next page but when I refresh the next it is sending values to database again and again. I want to stop it, here is function:

```
function technician_checklist_report_generated(){
global $current_user;
global $wpdb;  
$submit="";

if($_POST['customerid']!=""){
    $crow = $wpdb->get_row( 'SELECT customer_id, firstname, lastname, createdon, marina, vesselmodel, vesselname, vesselyear
                               FROM wp_yacht_customers 
                               WHERE customer_id= '.$_POST['customerid']
                             );

}

if($crow->customer_id!=""){


$table = 'wp_yatch_vessel_config_checklist';
array_pop($_POST); // delete last element in post array (submit)
$data = $_POST;
$format;

$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );
}

require(dirname(__FILE__) .'/view/technician-start-reporting.php');
}

add_shortcode('technician-start-reporting', 
'technician_checklist_report_generated');
```

When I reach to technician-start-reporting page it is sending data to MySQL again and again on browser refresh.

Is there any other way to go another page because I used wp_redirect and it showing error "header already sent... :

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and refine the formatting of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `wp_redirect` before content is sent to the browser.

Rather than process the form in the template[insite shortcode], you can hook an earlier action, like `wp_loaded` (this will be triggered before headers being sent).

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpv_process_form' );
function wpv_process_form(){
    if( isset( $_POST['customerid'] ) ):
        // process form, and then
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( $pid ) ); // redirect to desired page id
        exit();
    endif;
}
```

this way you'll be using less queries too.